# Can a function return an array?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, function

Can a function return an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
[Too short, but really... what more can be said?]

Comment: Would you? Such questions shouldn't be rewarded but locked.

Answer (score 5):

Sure.

```
Public Function Foo(ByVal bar as string) as String()
    ` return an array
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Public _RESULT(,) As String
        redim _RESULT(5,6)

        Public Function getResult() As String(,)
           Try
                 Return _RESULT
           Catch
               Dim s(0, 0)
               s(0, 0) = "0"
               Return s
            End Try
        End Function
```